# Installing Java on ubuntu

Tags: java

I have tried to install java on ubuntu, but cannot find a way to make it work. Is there a way to install java with apt-get?

Comment: ^^ skip to "The easy way"

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! ;-) If there are multiple answers that solve your problem please pick the best one.

Comment: follow this tutorial step by step and you are done! :) http://tipsonubuntu.com/2015/03/21/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 8):

Before I start, please **note** that the JDK also contains the JRE within it.

### Method 1:

To install the openJDK JDK and JRE 8 use (replace `8` with the version you want, such as `7` or `6`):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

### Method 2:

If you instead want to install the official Oracle JDK and JRE and definitely want to install through `apt-get` then do (you can replace the `8` with other versions such as `9`, or `7`):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

### Method 3:

Or if you want to install the official Oracle Java version manually:

1. Go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and click the download button:

   [image: Oracle Java Download Button]
2. Select the **Accept License Agreement** radio button (once you have read the license agreement).
3. Select the file you want to download, if you are running on a 32-bit machine click `jdk-[javaversion]-linux-i586.tar.gz` (`[javaversion]` replaced with the Java version, such as `8u60`), if 64-bit then `jdk-[javaversion]-linux-x64.tar.gz`.
4. Launch Terminal (CTRL + ALT + T), then `cd` to the directory where you downloaded the file to (probably `~/Downloads`), and run `tar -xvf /path/to/file.tar.gz` to unpack that archive into the directory the file is in, you may then move that unpacked archive into a desired location, such as the `/opt` directory (storing executable files in your home directory is a security risk).
5. Once you have done the above you may delete the original `.tar.gz` file, and then open up your `~/.bashrc` file in a desired file editor such as `gedit` or `vim`, I will be using `vim` in this example (install it with `sudo apt-get install vim` if it is not already installed). So run `vim ~/.bashrc` and then insert two new lines at the bottom of the file which read (that is with `/path/to/unpacked/archive` replaced with the path to the archive you just unpacked):

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/path/to/unpacked/archive
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```
6. Either restart Terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc` to start using the new `.bashrc` file.

   **Note:** With this method you will have to carry on doing this every time there  is a new Java version released which it will not notify you about.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: @king: Well, I don't know, but it still works for me. What version of Ubuntu are you running? If you carry on getting problems with this I suggest you post a new question because it's working for everyone else.

Comment: simon@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: @king: It appears as though OpenJDK 8 is not available for 14.04, only for 15.10, so you will have to get OpenJDK 7 if you want OpenJDK and to stick with 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

This package contains the Java Runtime Environment

Answer (score 1):

Open 'Terminal' and type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then:

for Java Development Kit:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/default-jdk/

for Java Runtime Environment

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/default-jre/

Answer (score 0):

There is a portable version

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u60-b27/jdk-8u60-linux-i586.tar.gz

download and extract to home folder

have links to java and javac at$HOME.